# ASIFormDataRequest POST returning website source code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, post, asihttprequest

I am using the following code to set the username and password to a form on a website:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
        [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setPostValue:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kUsername] forKey:@"username"];
        [request setPostValue:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kPassword] forKey:@"password"];
        [request setTimeOutSeconds:40];
        [request setDelegate:self];
        [request startAsynchronous];
```

However I am NSLogging the responseString from this request, and it is just printing out the source code of the website rather than any information.

Comment: What would be the expected return? What is the URL? Give some more info to make it less complicated to understand the question/issue.

Comment: POST requests are usually supposed to return something.  Check you are posting to the right url.

Comment: what's a way to show the actual website or show url instead of printing out the source code of the website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely a server-side issue or a logic error. In addition to `responseString`, look at `responseHeaders` and `responseStatusCode` to make sure you're getting what you expect.